# How to change a button width with an animation

Tags: android, android-animation

How to animate my button like the image below when I change its width to match parent.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this You can use [CProgressButton](https://github.com/jiang111/CProgressButton) or [FabButton](https://github.com/ckurtm/FabButton) libraries. There are also other beautiful button animations libraries like [android morphing button](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/android-morphing-button), [TH-ProgressButton](https://github.com/torryharris/TH-ProgressButton),  library.

[image]